# How to construct an xpath in Selenium with Python for the given HTML

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I'am using Selenium with python to execute an operation on telegram web, I get the web page, select the right group but when I try to enter I have to click "OK" or "Cancel", I want to click ok, but I can't figure out the right way to do it!

The situation is:

```
<button class="btn btn-md btn-md-primary" 
ng-switch="type" ng-click="$close(data)" 
ng-class="{'btn-md-danger': type == 'RESET_ACCOUNT' || type == 'HISTORY_LEAVE_AND_FLUSH' 
|| type == 'HISTORY_FLUSH_AND_DELETE' || type == 'HISTORY_FLUSH'}" my-focused="">
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!----><span ng-switch-default="" my-i18n="modal_ok" class="" style="">OK</span><!---->
</button>
```

the xpath is :`//*[@id="ng-app"]/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/button[2]/span`

I've tryied a lot of different configurations, from the most easier `browser.find_element_by_tag_name('//span[text()="OK"]').click` to something weird `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[6]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/button[2][contains(@span, "ng-switch-default")]').click` but I can't  figure out how to click on that "OK" in the `<span>` tag

Comment: `find_element_by_tag_name('//span[text()="OK"]')` Why `by_tag_name`? Have you tried the same with `by_xpath`?

Comment: @Andersson I've tried also by_xpath, it doesn't give me any error but it doesn't click the OK button, the program just skip ahead..

Comment: the simplest x-path would be //button/span[.='ok']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to click on the element with text as **OK** as it is an [**Angular**](https://angular.io/) element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC    
# other lines of code
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-md btn-md-primary' and @ng-switch='type']//span[contains(.,'OK')]"))).click()
```